# How to query mediastore so it filters out media files less than specific duration?

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

**What i tried:**

```
 EXCLUDE_DURATION = storageUtil.loadExcludedDuration();
 Log.d(TAG ,"EXCLUDE_DURATION: " + String.valueOf(EXCLUDE_DURATION));
 final String selection = SONG_IS_MUSIC + "!=0" + " WHERE " + SONG_DURATION + ">" + EXCLUDE_DURATION;

 // Querying the Media DATABASE.
 cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, projection1, selection, null, null);
```

So, In my activity I have a `SeekBar` which saves a duration in my `SharedPreferences`.

For example, the user chooses to exclude media tracks which are less than 30 seconds so I put the progress from the `SeekBar` in `SharedPreferences` and next time I start app I load it in my class where I load all songs. ( `EXCLUDE_DURATION = storageUtil.loadExcludedDuration();`
)

Now I'm pretty sure my selection in the query is just wrong and I'm not sure how to query only songs that are bigger than 30 seconds.

**EDIT:**

```
String SONG_IS_MUSIC = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC;
String SONG_DURATION = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
```

Comment: Found the solution, WHERE statement was wrong and has to be AND.